# Regex on pandas column to create new columns

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a pandas column:

df['Reviewer']

```
0    more, 25-34 Male on Treatment for 10 years or more
1    Idapida, 25-34 Female on Treatment for 2 to less than 5 years
2    Anna, 13-18 Female on Treatment for 5 to less than 10 years 
3    Kepons, 55-64 on Treatment for 1 to 6 months 
4    sammymaguire, 45-54 Female on Treatment for 1 to less than 2 years
```

I am looking to use the following regex patterns

```
ageRegex = re.compile('13-18|19-24|25-34|35-44|45-54|55-64|65-74|75 or 
over')
timeRegex = re.compile('less than 1 month|1 to 6 months|6 months to less 
than 1 year|1 to less than 2 years|2 to less than 5 years|5 to less than 
10 years|10 years or more')
genderRegex = re.compile('Male|Female')
```

to extract the age, time, and gender to new columns that would look something like this

```
0    25-34    10 years or more    Male 
1    25-34    Treatment for 2 to less than 5 years    Female 
2    13-18    Treatment for 5 to less than 10 years    Female 
3    55-64    Treatment for 1 to 6 months    na
4    45-54    Treatment for 1 to less than 2 years    Female
```

I've tried something like this

```
df['age'] = ageRegex.findall(df['Reviewer'])
```

but i get the error

```
expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```py
df["age"] = df["Reviewer"].str.extract('(13-18|19-24|25-34|35-44|45-54|55-64|65-74|75 or over)')

df["Time"] = df["Reviewer"].str.extract('(less than 1 month|1 to 6 months|6 months to less than 1 year|1 to less than 2 years|2 to less than 5 years|5 to less than 10 years|10 years or more)')

df["Gender"] = df["Reviewer"].str.extract('(Male|Female)')
```